# Ternary Golay code weight 6 words

Tags: abstract-algebra

**What are the 22 hexads with only non-negative entries of the ternary Golay code?**

According to the complete weight enumerator, the ternary Golay code has 22 words of weight 6 with no negative entries, i.e. vectors of shape $(1^6,0^6)$.

I wanted to find these words and therefore read some detailed description of how the ternary Golay code $\mathscr{C}_{12}$ is obtained from the tetracode $\mathscr{C}_{4}$, but I do not understand how this construction leads to one of the 22 "non-negative hexads".

There you take the MINIMOG array with shuffle numbering, then define "col" to be a word with + entries in one column and 0 entries elsewhere (+ representing 1, - representing -1). Further label the rows of the array 0, +, - and define "tet" to be a word of weight 4, with + digits being in the places corresponding to a tetracodeword.
(For instance ++-0 is a tetracodeword, so the refering "tet" would have 4 positive entries: the first one being in the first column, second row, the second one being in the second column, second row, the third one being in the third column, third row and the last one being in the forth column, first row.)

Then the ternary Golay code is defined by the observation that modulo $\mathscr{C}_{12}$, any column is congruent to the negative of any tetrad.
In particular, this implies that
col-col, col+tet, tet-tet, col+col-tet
all yield signed hexads ($\mathscr{C}_{12}$-words of weight 6).

You can find this description (a bit more detailed) in Conway's work "Sphere Packings, Lattices and Groups".

First, I am not quite sure why for example col-col is implied to be a $\mathscr{C}_{12}$-word by the observation. For me only col+tet was obvious.
But I was more surprised by the following statements:
If we ignore signs, then from these signed hexads we get the 132 hexads of the Steiner system S(5,6,12). Any such unsigned hexad can be signed in two ways, the one you first think of and its negative.

But I can not see any possibility to get a hexad with only positive non-zero entries by this construction.
Any above combination has at least one entry + and one entry -, so that it cannot provide such a "non-negative" hexad.

Thus, I am wondering if this construction is complete, or if for example col+col is also a possible combination. Otherwise, I would like to know what are the non-negative hexads of the ternary Golay code (and how they can be obtained).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that these code words can be easily deduced from the generator matrix of the code, and I have computed all of them (sadly with a not very satisfying result for my purpose).
Hence, this question is basically solved, even if I still do not understand the construction based on the tetracode. If someone knows how to obtain the required words from that construction, I would be glad to know.